How to implement Drag and Drop in react-native web and mobile?
I want to make drag and drop with react native on the web, but I can't find any library that I can use to make it work on the web and the mobile. Most of the packages I found only works on mobile, ex: react-native-drax, rn-dnd-kanban. If there's a package that I could use to create a drag-and-drop that works on both web and mobile, please tell me.
I already made an app that have drag-and-drop feature with expo with react-native-gesture-handler ~2.16.1 and react-native-reanimated ~3.10.1. But what I made have issue that it only works on web and have poorly performance that in consumes so much CPU.
Here's the code that I'm working on.
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  runOnJS,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
  withTiming,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { generateNewId } from "@/utils/index";

interface Card {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

interface Column {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  cards: Card[];
}

interface Position {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface DragContext {
  type: "card" | "column";
  columnId: string;
  cardId?: string;
  cardTitle?: string;
}

const initialColumns: Column[] = [
  {
    id: "b1c1",
    title: "To Do",
    cards: [
      { id: "b1c1c1", title: "Workspace - Board" },
      { id: "b1c1c2", title: "Workspace - Priority" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "b1c2",
    title: "In Progress",
    cards: [{ id: "b1c2c1", title: "Workspace - Drag And Drop" }],
  },
  { id: "b1c3", title: "Done", cards: [] },
  {
    id: "b1c4",
    title: "Upcoming",
    cards: [{ id: "b1c4c1", title: "Workspace - Backends" }],
  },
  {
    id: "b1c5",
    title: "Pending",
    cards: [{ id: "b1c5c1", title: "Workspace - Assignee" }],
  },
];

function Box({
  children,
  style,
  id,
  activeBox,
  setActiveBox,
  columnId,
  title,
  isColumn = false,
  onDragStart,
  onDragMove,
  onDragEnd,
  measureRef,
  dragHandleRef,
  isDragging,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  style: any;
  id: string;
  activeBox: string;
  setActiveBox: (id: string) => void;
  columnId?: string;
  title?: string;
  isColumn?: boolean;
  onDragStart?: (context: DragContext) => void;
  onDragMove?: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  onDragEnd?: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  measureRef?: (ref: View) => void;
  dragHandleRef?: React.RefObject<View>;
  isDragging?: boolean;
}) {
  const pressed = useSharedValue(false);
  const offset = useSharedValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const boxRef = useRef<View>(null);
  const startPosition = useSharedValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (boxRef.current && measureRef) {
      measureRef(boxRef.current);
    }
  }, [measureRef]);

  const pan = Gesture.Pan()
    .minDistance(1)
    .onBegin((event) => {
      // Only start drag if touching drag handle for columns
      if (isColumn && dragHandleRef?.current) {
        dragHandleRef.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
          const isTouchInHandle =
            event.absoluteX >= pageX &&
            event.absoluteX <= pageX + width &&
            event.absoluteY >= pageY &&
            event.absoluteY <= pageY + height;

          if (!isTouchInHandle) return;
        });
      }

      pressed.value = true;
      startPosition.value = { x: event.absoluteX, y: event.absoluteY };
      runOnJS(setActiveBox)(id);
      if (onDragStart) {
        runOnJS(onDragStart)({
          type: isColumn ? "column" : "card",
          columnId: isColumn ? id : columnId || "",
          cardId: isColumn ? undefined : id,
          cardTitle: isColumn ? undefined : title,
        });
      }
    })
    .onChange((event) => {
      offset.value = {
        x: event.translationX,
        y: event.translationY,
      };
      if (onDragMove) {
        runOnJS(onDragMove)(event.absoluteX, event.absoluteY);
      }
    })
    .onFinalize((event) => {
      if (onDragEnd) {
        runOnJS(onDragEnd)(event.absoluteX, event.absoluteY);
      }
      offset.value = withSpring({ x: 0, y: 0 });
      pressed.value = false;
      if (activeBox === id) runOnJS(setActiveBox)("");
    });

  const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      { translateX: offset.value.x },
      { translateY: offset.value.y },
      { scale: withTiming(pressed.value ? 1.1 : 1) },
    ],
    backgroundColor: pressed.value ? "#FFE04B" : style.backgroundColor,
    borderRadius: withTiming(pressed.value ? 25 : 10, { duration: 200 }),
    zIndex: pressed.value ? 999 : 1,
    opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
  }));

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.View ref={boxRef} style={[style, animatedStyles]}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
          <View ref={dragHandleRef} style={styles.dragHandle}>
            <Text style={styles.dragHandleText}>:::</Text>
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
        <View>{children}</View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [activeBox, setActiveBox] = useState("");
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(initialColumns);
  const [columnMeasurements, setColumnMeasurements] = useState<
    Map<string, Position>
  >(new Map());
  const [cardMeasurements, setCardMeasurements] = useState<
    Map<string, Position>
  >(new Map());
  const [dragContext, setDragContext] = useState<DragContext | null>(null);
  const [hoveredColumn, setHoveredColumn] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [hoveredCard, setHoveredCard] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const columnHandleRefs = useRef<Map<string, React.RefObject<View>>>(
    new Map()
  );

  // Initialize refs for column handles
  useEffect(() => {
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      if (!columnHandleRefs.current.has(column.id)) {
        columnHandleRefs.current.set(column.id, React.createRef<View>());
      }
    });
  }, [columns]);

  const measureColumn = (columnId: string) => (ref: View) => {
    ref.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      setColumnMeasurements((prev) =>
        new Map(prev).set(columnId, {
          x: pageX,
          y: pageY,
          width,
          height,
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const measureCard = (cardId: string) => (ref: View) => {
    ref.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
      setCardMeasurements((prev) =>
        new Map(prev).set(cardId, {
          x: pageX,
          y: pageY,
          width,
          height,
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const handleDragStart = (context: DragContext) => {
    setDragContext(context);
    console.log("Started dragging:", context);
  };

  const handleDragMove = (x: number, y: number) => {
    if (!dragContext) return;

    // Reset hoveredCard and hoveredColumn flags initially
    let isHoveringCard = false;
    let isHoveringColumn = false;

    // Handle column movement
    columnMeasurements.forEach((position, columnId) => {
      if (
        x >= position.x &&
        x <= position.x + position.width &&
        y >= position.y &&
        y <= position.y + position.height
      ) {
        isHoveringColumn = true; // Set flag if hovering over a column
        if (hoveredColumn !== columnId) {
          setHoveredColumn(columnId);
          console.log(`Hovering over column: ${columnId}`);
        }
      }
    });
    // If not hovering over any column, reset hoveredColumn
    if (!isHoveringColumn) {
      setHoveredColumn(null);
    }

    // Handle card movement
    cardMeasurements.forEach((position, cardId) => {
      if (
        cardId !== dragContext.cardId &&
        x >= position.x &&
        x <= position.x + position.width &&
        y >= position.y &&
        y <= position.y + position.height
      ) {
        isHoveringCard = true; // Set flag if hovering over a card
        if (hoveredCard !== cardId) {
          setHoveredCard(cardId);
          console.log(`Hovering over card: ${cardId}`);
        }
      }
    });
    // If not hovering over any card, reset hoveredCard
    if (!isHoveringCard) {
      setHoveredCard(null);
    }
  };

  function handleDragEnd() {
    if (!dragContext) return;

    // Check if the drag ended over a column
    if (dragContext.type === "card" && hoveredColumn) {
      setColumns((prevColumns) =>
        prevColumns.map((column) => {
          if (column.id === hoveredColumn) {
            let updatedCards = column.cards.filter(
              (card) => card.id !== dragContext.cardId
            );

            const targetIndex = hoveredCard
              ? updatedCards.findIndex((card) => card.id === hoveredCard)
              : updatedCards.length;

            updatedCards.splice(targetIndex, 0, {
              id: dragContext.cardId!,
              title: dragContext.cardTitle!,
            });

            return { ...column, cards: updatedCards };
          } else if (column.id === dragContext.columnId) {
            // Remove card from its original column
            return {
              ...column,
              cards: column.cards.filter(
                (card) => card.id !== dragContext.cardId
              ),
            };
          }
          return column;
        })
      );
    }
    //     // Reset states
    setDragContext(null);
    setHoveredColumn(null);
    setHoveredCard(null);
    return;
  }

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView horizontal style={styles.scrollView}>
        {columns.map((column) => (
          <Box
            key={column.id}
            id={column.id}
            activeBox={activeBox}
            setActiveBox={setActiveBox}
            style={[
              styles.columnBox,
              hoveredColumn === column.id && styles.columnBoxHovered,
            ]}
            isColumn={true}
            onDragStart={handleDragStart}
            onDragMove={handleDragMove}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            measureRef={measureColumn(column.id)}
            dragHandleRef={columnHandleRefs.current.get(column.id)}
          >
            <Text style={styles.columnTitle}>{column.title}</Text>
            {column.cards.map((card) => (
              <Box
                key={card.id}
                id={card.id}
                title={card.title}
                activeBox={activeBox}
                setActiveBox={setActiveBox}
                columnId={column.id}
                style={[
                  styles.card,
                  hoveredCard === card.id && styles.cardHovered,
                ]}
                onDragStart={handleDragStart}
                onDragMove={handleDragMove}
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                measureRef={measureCard(card.id)}
                isDragging={dragContext?.cardId === card.id}
              >
                <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{card.title}</Text>
              </Box>
            ))}
          </Box>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  columnBox: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#e0e0e0e0",
    borderRadius: 8,
    width: 280,
    margin: 10,
    minHeight: 400,
  },
  columnBoxHovered: {
    backgroundColor: "#e0e0e0",
    borderColor: "#2196F3",
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  columnTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "600",
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: "#333",
  },
  card: {
    marginVertical: 5,
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 8,
    width: "100%",
    height: 100,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    elevation: 3,
  },
  cardHovered: {
    backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
    borderColor: "#2196F3",
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  cardTitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#333",
  },
  dragHandle: {
    padding: 5,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  dragHandleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#999",
  },
});


Have you looked at https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout?
It supports drag and drop and also resizing on web with React, and I believe some people have gotten it to work well on mobile interfaces by adding a hold toggle to enable dragging vs scrolling.
I also have a web demo template here.
Hope this helps!
